# Canvas Animation CPU issue

Tags: canvas, fabricjs

We are using fabricjs Animation Easing with Sprite and it's kinda lagging. We also check other canvas project without fabricjs and they are also eating much of cpu. Is there a good way to solve this under canvas?

Comment: There are plenty of ways to improve the speed of a game. You should be getting hundreds of sprites + at full frame rate 60fps on a medium machine. But you do not provide us with code so we can not tell you where the issues are and how to overcome them.

Comment: Not sure what code to show, simply using `Sprite` custom function of fabricjs and `animate` official thing of the fabric on it. WIth that combination CPU get crazy after 10 objects.

Comment: If I were writing a game the last thing I would do is use a 3rd party interface. To draw a sprite without 3rd party stuff `function drawSprite(img,x,y,cx,cy,sx,sy,rot,alpha){ctx.setTransform(sx,0,0,sy,x,y); ctx.rotate(rot); ctx.globalAlpha=alpha; ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,img.width,img.height,-cx,-cy,img.width,img.height)}` draws an image at its center `cx`,`cy` at `x`,`y` scaled `sx`,`sy`, rotated `rot` and fade `alpha`. A 6 year old laptop can do that 60000 times a second. Ask yourself what does fabric.js offer that you can not do with a few lines of code without it. BTW its not design for games

Comment: Exactly, fabricjs does so much stuff to help you selecting, scaling, emitting events that it may no be appropriate for games in current status. Also the main render loop lack of RAF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm not a FabricJS Guru!*

So take my analysis lightly... :-)

**Why your animation might be lagging when many objects are involved**

As @Blindman67 implies in his comment, FabricJS's "smart" objects are too heavy to be animated in very large quantities.

- Smart == event-aware, code-controllable (*Nice!*).
- Heavy == resource intensive (*not so Nice!*).

**If your animations are almost-but-not-quite responsive...**

You might try *grouping your re-renderings to do fewer redraws during your animation cycle*.

- Don't set the `onChange` callback for anything that is animating.
- When animation starts, create a separate `requestAnimationFrame` (aka rAF) callback and only re-render (with `canvas.renderAll`) in this separate rAF loop.
- Throttle the rAF callback loop to fire at a speed that reduces lagging but which is still visually appealing.

**Notes:**

By default, the rAF loop that FabricJS uses will try to loop at 60fps. Assigning `onChange` callbacks on every animating object will almost certainly cause that animation loop to redraw at 60 frames-per-second.

Grouping causes all redrawings to be done in a single animation loop so that the re-renderings can be done at less than the overwhelming 60fps -- perhaps 30fps. This slower fps likely will not impair the animation effect but *will give the CPU+GPU twice the time to do their renderings!*

To help, the rAF loop comes with a timestamp argument that you can use to throttle the loop to execute code at less than 60fps.

**Here's starting code for you to build upon**

```
// animation related vars
var fps=30;
var delay=1000/fps;
var nextTime=0;
var isAnimating=true;
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

// Usage:
// * call startAnimating()
// * Set many objects to .animate
// * Optionally, when all animating objects report "onComplete"
//       call stopAnimating()

function startAnimating(){
    // set the isAnimating flag to start the animation loop
    isAnimating=true;
}

function stopAnimating(){
    isAnimating=false;
}

function animate(time){
    // if we're not animating anything or if desired delay 
    //    hasn't occurred, just request another loop and return
    if(!isAnimating || time<nextTime){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        return;
    }
    // set nextTime to the next elapsed time
    nextTime=time+delay;
    // re-render everything
    canvas.renderAll();
    // request another loop
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that solution was not too good for me.
I propose a solution I found.
The trick is to convert the canvas to svg and later apply animations to it. Now, There is no fan noise!!

When you have your canvas rendered

```
    canvas.loadFromJSON(state, 
     canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), 
    function (o, object) {

   })
```

Yo can convert it to a SVG string

```
 var svg = canvas.toSVG();
```

Now, sure there are better ways to do that but for example:

```
svg = svg.replace('<text', '<text id="im"');
svg = svg.replace('<image style', '<image class="ima" style').replace('<image style', '<image class="ima" style');
$('body').html(svg);
$('#im').css(
    {
        'animation-duration': dur+'s',
        'transform-origin': '50% 50%',
        'animation-name': 'lefter'
    }
);
$('.ima').css(
    {
        'animation-duration': dur+'s',
        'transform-origin': '50% 50%',
        'animation-name': 'righter'
    }
);
```

Don't forget to add the CSS for animations:

```
svg {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px
    }



    @keyframes lefter {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            transform: translate(30px, 0);
        }
    }



    @keyframes righter {
        0% {
            transform: translate(0, 0);
        }

        100% {
            transform: scale(1.03);
        }
    }
```

In my application there are running axios + polifyll + Fabric